# Latest compatible version of kafka-clientlib with Cloud SDK 4.11

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to use calm-kafka-clientlib (any version) with the latest SAP Cloud SDK (4.11), and I'm getting the following error:

> Not able to process incoming message

The reason is:
`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.vavr.control.Try com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.Property.ofTry(io.vavr.control.Try)'                                                                                      at com.sap.calm.x.kafkaclient.message.CalmMessageDeliveryHelper.executeWithDwCContext(CalmMessageDeliveryHelper.java:118)`

Do I understand well that the version of SAP Cloud SDK which is working with kafka-clientlib is only 3.78?

Below is the full log.

Any suggestions?

NB I've tried different versions of kafka-clientlib. Now I'm using latest release version `1.1.0-20230324094318_6c165b6d08b9e50036fe280c122772b9d0775b90` with SAP Cloud SDK version 3.78.

```bash
Caused by: com.sap.dwc.kafka.core.FatalMessagingException: Not able to process incoming message                                                                                                                      
        at com.sap.calm.x.kafkaclient.event.TenantMessageDispatcherOnReceived.onKafkaMessageReceived(TenantMessageDispatcherOnReceived.java:114) ~[calm-kafka-clientlib-1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019d
acef295803733989.jar:1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733989]                                                                                                                                  
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor118.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]                                                                                                                           
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]                                                                                         
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]                                                                                                                                       
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:344) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]                                                
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]                                            
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]                                      
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]                                      
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]                                        
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]                                        
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]                                                      
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]                                                      
        at com.sap.dwc.kafka.listener.TenantTopicListener.onMessage(TenantTopicListener.java:21) ~[calm-kafka-clientlib-1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733989.jar:1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78
f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733989]                                                                                                                                                                                  
        at com.sap.dwc.kafka.listener.TenantTopicListener.onMessage(TenantTopicListener.java:12) ~[calm-kafka-clientlib-1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733989.jar:1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78
f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733989]                                                                                                                                                                                  
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.FilteringMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(FilteringMessageListenerAdapter.java:77) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]                                             
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.FilteringMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(FilteringMessageListenerAdapter.java:118) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]                                            
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.FilteringMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(FilteringMessageListenerAdapter.java:36) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]                                             
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2789) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]                              
        ... 11 common frames omitted                                                                                                                                                                                 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.vavr.control.Try com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.Property.ofTry(io.vavr.control.Try)'                                                                             
        at com.sap.calm.x.kafkaclient.message.CalmMessageDeliveryHelper.executeWithDwCContext(CalmMessageDeliveryHelper.java:118) ~[calm-kafka-clientlib-1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef29580373398
9.jar:1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733989]                                                                                                                                                 
        at com.sap.calm.x.kafkaclient.message.CalmMessageDeliveryHelper.executeDelivery(CalmMessageDeliveryHelper.java:85) ~[calm-kafka-clientlib-1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733989.jar:1
.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733989]                                                                                                                                                        
        at com.sap.calm.x.kafkaclient.core.AbstractMessageConsumerHandler.onInboundMessage(AbstractMessageConsumerHandler.java:113) ~[calm-kafka-clientlib-1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733
989.jar:1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733989]                                                                                                                                               
        at com.sap.calm.x.kafkaclient.event.TenantMessageDispatcherOnReceived.processMessage(TenantMessageDispatcherOnReceived.java:201) ~[calm-kafka-clientlib-1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef2958
03733989.jar:1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733989]                                                                                                                                          
        at com.sap.calm.x.kafkaclient.event.TenantMessageDispatcherOnReceived.processTenantTopicIncomingMessage(TenantMessageDispatcherOnReceived.java:134) ~[calm-kafka-clientlib-1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938dd
d610634019dacef295803733989.jar:1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733989]                                                                                                                       
        at com.sap.calm.x.kafkaclient.event.TenantMessageDispatcherOnReceived.onKafkaMessageReceived(TenantMessageDispatcherOnReceived.java:98) ~[calm-kafka-clientlib-1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019da
cef295803733989.jar:1.1.0-20230313100519_6abf78f8938ddd610634019dacef295803733989]                                                                                                                                   
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

A corresponding PR has been created: https://github.tools.sap/CALMBuild/x-calm-kafka-clientlib/pull/815. Need to wait.